# Why?, I can not access the properties of a one to one in jbuilder, Rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I have a API developed in **Rails 4.2.5** and in this problem, I try to show all users, but **each user have a relation one to one**, for example **one user have one profile**, and when I try to access, for example to name that exist in the relation, I can not, This is mi code:

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.users @users do |user|
  json.type user.class.name.underscore.pluralize
  json.id user.id
  json.attributes do |json|
    json.name user.name
    json.email user.email
  end

  json.profile do
    json.gender user.profile.gender
  end

end
```

And when I access to relation directly, with this code it works, I can view all information from the profile

```
json.profile do
    json.gender user.profile
  end
```

But when I try to access to other properties in specific, for example:

```
json.profile do
    json.gender user.profile.gender
  end
```

I can not, only shows me this error:

```
undefined method `gender' for nil:NilClass

json.profile do
    json.gender user.profile.gender
end
```

Models:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried ActiveModelSerializers? https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: Please show your belongs_to on the User model.